# Alternative to Synthesia, for MIDI instrument

Tags: windows, gratis, music-production, midi

I've been using [Synthesia](http://www.synthesiagame.com/) to play my MIDI instrument, as it allows for a nice visualization of the notes and many instruments. The problem is that this program is neither free nor very portable, so every time I need to change the computer I play with I would need to reinstall it. I'm not interested in the whole "play songs" thing.

I just need a program that makes the sound my instrument says, with the sound font I decide. Anything else is a plus.

I have been snooping around a lot, the keyword being "MIDI instrument", "MIDI synth" etc. But I've only got pricey music recording programs (not what I'm looking for), and many '98 style freeware websites. I'm now using [Coolsoft virtualMIDIsynth](http://coolsoft.altervista.org/en/virtualmidisynth), that does the sound but I can't manage to change instrument.

Comment: @ThomasWeller  I know, it seems such a simple problem, yet apparently no one thought of it in the last 8 years... Or they found a very different name for it

Answer (score 2):

Since I own a license for Synthesia I could check in "Free play" mode what you want and I think I found the issue: there seem to be many programs that do play notes which are received via MIDI, but some of them don't respect the instrument setting and will only play a single instrument instead. Synthesia does respect the instrument setting.

Since you already seem to have a license for Synthesia, I wanted to point out that it was explicitly mentioned that I may use it on many different PCs as long as I use it only once.

In addition I want to recommend [SyFonOne](http://www.synthfont.com/Downloads.html) (just pick the right link from that page):

- a small tool (6 MB), so it's quite "portable" - I have not tried running it without installation, though
- is gratis (freeware), consider a donation if you like it
- works on Windows (tested on Windows 10)
- changes the instrument when you change it on the keyboard (tested with Yamaha PSR 400)
- can load SF2 sound fonts (tested with a 144 MB Fluid R3 file)

[image: SyFonOne]

Comment: The reason I'm not using synthesia is because I don't have a licence. I will try the program you are proposing